# $K$-functional between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ for a specific sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, asymptotics

- **Short version:**

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, Let $$
p_n(k) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}, \qquad 1\leq k\leq n-1
$$
and consider $$
\kappa_{p_n}(t) = \inf\{ \lVert u\rVert_1+t\lVert v\rVert_2 : u\in\ell_1, v\in\ell_2\text{ s.t. } u+v=p_n\}
$$
For a fixed small constant $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$, what is the asymptotic expression (as $n\to\infty)$ of $t=t(n,\varepsilon)$ such that
$$\kappa_{p_n}(t) =(1-2\varepsilon)\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k\ln k} \tag{$\dagger$}
$$?

- **Long version:**

Recall that for any sequence $a\in\ell_1+\ell_2$, we can defined the K-functional (between $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2)$ as the concave, non-decreasing function $\kappa_p\colon(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$
$$
\kappa_p(t) = \inf\{ \lVert u\rVert_1+t\lVert v\rVert_2 : u\in\ell_1, v\in\ell_2\text{ s.t. } u+v=p\}
$$ (see e.g. [this previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/248921/properties-of-the-optimal-decomposition-for-the-k-functional-between-ell-1) for more properties).

It is also known (for the continuous case $L_1+L_2$, but I am pretty sure the proof extends to the discrete case) that for any given $t>0$ an optimal decomposition $(u_t,v_t)$ yiedling the value $\kappa_p(t)$ is of the form (assuming wlog that $a\geq 0$)
$$
v_t = \min(a, \lambda_t), \qquad u_t = a-v
$$
for some threshold $\lambda_t \geq 0$.

---

This being said, I have been repeatedly failing to find a tight enough (possibly asymptotic with regard to $n$) expression for $\kappa_{p_n}(t)$, where $(p_n)_n$ is a sequence of probability distributions defined as
$$
p_n(k) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \frac{1}{c_n}\cdot \frac{1}{(k+1)\ln(k+1)}, \qquad 1\leq k\leq n-1
$$
and $0$ for $k\geq n$; where $c_n \stackrel{\rm def}{=}\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k\ln k}$ is a normalizing constant satisfying
$c_n = \ln\ln n - K+o(1)$ for some constant $K$ (which can be found, e.g., via Euler—MacLaurin).

> More specifically, my end goal would be to find an asymptotic equivalent (or even expansion to lower order terms) to the value $t^\ast(n,\varepsilon)$ solution of the equation
>   $$
>  \kappa_{p_n}(t) = 1-2\varepsilon \tag{1}
> $$
>   where $\varepsilon \in (0,1/2)$ is to be thought of as a small constant.

I tried to tackle that by (i) finding an expression or sufficiently good asymptotic expansion of $\lVert u_\lambda\rVert_1+t\lVert v_\lambda\rVert_2$ (for fixed $t$, as a function of $\lambda$), (ii) minimizing this w.r.t. $\lambda$ to find an expression (or sufficiently good asymptotic expansion) of $\kappa_{p_n}(t)$; and (iii) solve (1) approximately using the expression of (ii) in lieu of $\kappa_{p_n}(t)$.

However, I was stuck at (i) for the discrete case; trying to consider the $L_1+L_2$ analog instead (continuous case) for a start, I got stuck at either (ii) or (iii) -- I am unclear which, as repeating the computations kept giving me either different results or nonsense.

Any clue, idea, or suggestion on what I could do (or what the "right" approach and answer are)?

---

- **Additional:**
  The answer to $(\dagger)$ (and of (1)), even though not to the more general question of the asymptotic of $\kappa_{p_n}(t)$, should satisfy
  $$
  e^{(\ln n)^{\frac{1}{2}-c'\varepsilon}} \leq \kappa_{p_n}^{-1}(1-2\varepsilon) \leq e^{(\ln n)^{\frac{1}{2}-c\varepsilon}} \tag{2}
  $$
  where $c,c'>0$ are absolute constants; leading me to conjecture that $\kappa_{p_n}^{-1}(1-2\varepsilon) = e^{(1+o(1))(\ln n)^{\frac{1}{2}-c\varepsilon}}$ for asome absolute constant $c>0$.

The reason for (2) is rather long-winded, but basically follows from a distribution testing question. [VV14] and [BCG17] both established bounds on the complexity $\Phi$ of a specific problem ("identity testing"), which for arbitrary discrete distribution $p$ and $\varepsilon \in(0,1]$ are respectively
$$
\Omega\left(\frac{\lVert p^{-\max}_{-\varepsilon}\rVert_{2/3}}{\varepsilon^2}\right)\leq \Phi(p,\varepsilon) \leq O\left(\frac{\lVert p^{-\max}_{-\varepsilon/16}\rVert_{2/3}}{\varepsilon^2}\right) \tag{3}
$$ and
$$
\Omega\left(\frac{\kappa_{p_n}^{-1}(1-2\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}\right)\leq \Phi(p,\varepsilon) \leq O\left(\frac{\kappa_{p_n}^{-1}(1-\frac{\varepsilon}{9})}{\varepsilon^2}\right). \tag{4}
$$ 
Without delving into exactly what the functional $p\mapsto \lVert p^{-\max}_{-\varepsilon}\rVert_{2/3}$ in (3) is (it is the $2/3$-norm of a vector obtained from $p$), computing its asymptotics for $(p_n)_n$ is easier than that of $\kappa_{p_n}^{-1}(1-2\varepsilon)$. By doing so (assuming I didn't make a mistake in the computation), and putting together the inequalities (3) and (4), we get the inequalities from (2).

---

`[VV14]` Gregory Valiant and Paul Valiant. An automatic inequality prover and instance optimal identity testing. In Proceedings of FOCS, 2014.

`[BCG17]` Eric Blais, Clément L. Canonne, and Tom Gur. Distribution testing lower bounds via reductions
from communication complexity. In IEEE Conference on Computational Complexity (CCC), 2017.

Comment: Based on an completely different approach (i.e., using loose upper and upper bounds with regard to a quantity a bit simpler to compute), I expect the answer of the latter (i.e., $t$ for which (1) holds) to be of the form $e^{(1+o(1))(\ln n)^{\frac{1}{2}-c\varepsilon}}$ for some constant $c>0$.

Comment: (If anyone is interested, I can detail how the bound in the previous comment is obtained, even though it only gives loose bounds for (1) and does not provide the answer for the general question of establishing the asymptotics of $\kappa_p(t)$. I also don't believe it'll give a lot of insight, to be honest — at least it gave none to me)

Comment: Added what the rationale behind the above comment is to the question.